# how to correct use simditor with symfony and webpack?

Tags: javascript, symfony, webpack

I faced with problem when try to use simditor with symfony project with webpack

package.json

```
  "dependencies": {
    "simditor": "^2.3.28",
    "simple-hotkeys": "^1.0.3",
    "simple-module": "^3.0.3",
    "simple-uploader": "^3.0.0",
```

in my js file

```
import 'simple-module'
import 'simple-hotkeys'
import 'simple-uploader'
import Simditor from 'simditor'

    let form = modal.find("form");
    $.each(form.find('textarea'), function (k, v) {

    var editor = new Simditor({
        textarea: v
        });
    });
```

and faced with

```
TypeError: Simditor.connect is not a function
```

what I missed, how to correct use simditor with symfony and webpack ?